# Making PyScripter to work with QGIS Python modules

Tags: pyqgis, pyscripter

I have been reading several other solutions, none of them seems to work and I don't know if it is because I am doing something wrong, or because they are for an older version.

I have unistalled everything QGIS related, and downloaded the latest OSGEO4W installer and install the QGS-LTR (3.22.7).

It has been installed in `C:\OSGeo4W\` without the 64 at the end. But it is the 64 bits version.

Now I have followed the instructions in this page https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins/ide_debugging.html

and I have a bat file called Pyscripter.bat sitting next to the other bat files with this content:

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\gdal16.bat
@echo off
call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
if not exist "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin\qgisgrass7.dll" goto nograss
set savedpath=%PATH%
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat"
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\bin;%savedpath%
:nograss
@echo off
path %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\bin;%PATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis-ltr
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000
set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis-ltr\qtplugins;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins
@echo off
path %PATH%;%GISBASE%\bin
Start "" "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\PyScripter.exe" "--python39 --pythondllpath=C:\OSGeo4W\bin"
```

PyScripter refuses to work with the executable in `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`, it just closes itself if you force it to use it. It can work with the executable at `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\` but then once it is loaded. You can't import qgis, so it isn't loading properly.

I think I have followed the instructions on the page correctly, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you install the 64bit version of PyScripter?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the path would be \Program Files (x86)\ (I think).